# React JSON array order

Tags: reactjs

I have a json file that I am reading data from. It's an array of items. I would like to click the first item in the array and move it to the last index. For example var `animals=["cow", "dog", "cat"]`. If I click on cow I want it to now be the last item so the new array would be `animals=["dog", "cat", "cow"]`. I need to do this as an onClick event and can't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help anyone has.

I was thinking possibly a `forEach` but not sure how to structure it for various clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```js
class Animals extends React.Component {
  state = {
    animals: [
      {name: "cow"},
      {name: "dog"},
      {name: "cat"}
     ] // the initial list
  };

  onAnimalClick = e => {
    const { animals } = this.state; // current list
    const index = e.target.dataset.index; // the index of the clicked item
    const [clicked] = animals.splice(index, 1); // extract the item and delete it from the array

    this.setState({
      animals: [...animals, clicked] // add the clicked item to the end
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { animals } = this.state;

    return animals.map((a, i) => (
      <div onClick={this.onAnimalClick} data-index={i}>
        {a.name}
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Animals />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ray hatfield this is awesome. I need to clarify that it's an array of objects. My mistake was writing items. Is there a way to do this for objects? I have the info in the form of bootstrap cards so when one is marked as read I'd like it to got to the bottom and so on just like above. Hope this clarifies and thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: The process is exactly the same. The item is identified by its index in the list. I've updated the snippet to use objects instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked after I refactored to my code. Only thing is that i'm now getting repeats like if I have 2 objects in the array 4 show up on the page or if I have 3, 6 show up. https://helpinghandapp.herokuapp.com/css you can see what I mean here. do you happen to know what would cause the repeat? again seriously thanks for any insight. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You've got a nested iteration of `this.state.css` in your CSS component: an outer one rendering a `div` with an `onClick`, and then again inside the `div` to render `Context`.

Comment: I was thinking about this earlier and I don't think moving an item to the end of the array is the right approach. It would be better to flag the item as read (as a property on the item itself), and then just sort the array accordingly. The read/unread state shouldn't be managed internally by the thing doing the rendering.

Comment: thank you so much for your thoughts and your help. you've been awesome. I will go with the approach of maybe an onClick handler to change the styling of the Read/Unread. seems like a better bet. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with React hooks:

```
const App = () => {
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState(['cow', 'dog', 'cat']);

  const sortAnimals = () => {
    let myAnimals = [...animals];
    myAnimals.push(myAnimals.shift());
    setAnimals(myAnimals);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        animals.map(animal => <button onClick={sortAnimals}>{animal}</button>)
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This doesn't account for which animal was clicked.

Comment: Yep, but he mentioned to only clicked the first item and move it to the last.

Comment: I think it's a she.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check her name. You're right @JuniusL.